# General Flask: When to use javascript vs using POST/GET and a python defined function

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

As the question asks,

when should one resort to javascript vs making get/post calls when trying to manipulate or change page info?

I understand get/post calls the server and javascript doesn't, but I don't truly understand the significance of this. Are there performance issues associated with significant server calls?

Any general rules of thumb to keep in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manipulate the page info after it has been rendered you should generally use JS and not use Flask, for at least two reasons;

- JS is executed on the client side and is therefore faster.
- JS does not need to re-render the page, after a server method call, so you do not get a flicker of a refresh, and ping latency.
- arguably your code is probably easier to maintain without the need of passing data back and forth between client and server (but maybe not)
- for high volume users you avoid troubling your server with many, many requests upon updates.

If the updates are generally rare and complicated code for which python is more suitable then a route may be acceptable.

Personally I use both and combined. I use JS to call Flask API routes so then my main rendered page can access JSON data that is returned from Flask API in the background. This is common technique and you should consider researching Flask API AJAX query. Lots of tutorials on that one.